# IndexError: list index out of range, but error is inconsistent?

Tags: python-2.7

I am in a intro to GIS programming class and doing a hangman game for my final project. I am very much an amateur so this might be an easy fix that I am not understanding...Here is my code:

```
import random, sys 
class Hangman:
    def __init__(self,word):
            self.word = word
            self.incorrect_letters = []
            self.letters_guessed = []

    def hangman_loss(self):
            return self.hangman_win() or (len(self.incorrect_letters) == 7)

    def hangman_win(self):
            if '_' not in self.unknown_word():
                    return True
            return False 

    def game_stats(self):
            print graphic[len(self.incorrect_letters)]
            print 'Guess the word: ' + self.unknown_word()
            print 'Incorrect Letters: ', 
            for letter in self.incorrect_letters:
                    print letter, 
            print        

    def unknown_word(self):
            rtn = ''
            for letter in self.word:
                    if letter not in self.letters_guessed:
                            rtn += '_'
                    else:
                            rtn += letter
            return rtn

    def guess(self,letter):
            if letter in self.word and letter not in self.letters_guessed:
                    self.letters_guessed.append(letter)
            elif letter not in self.word and letter not in self.incorrect_letters:
                    self.incorrect_letters.append(letter)
            else:
                    return False
            return True

graphic = [
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n      |   \n      |   \n      |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n      |   \n      |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n  |   |   \n      |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n  |   |   \n      |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n /|   |   \n      |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n /|\\  |   \n      |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n /|\\  |   \n /    |   \n      |   \n========= \n',
'  +---+   \n  |   |   \n  0   |   \n /|\\  |   \n / \\  |   \n      |   \n========= \n'
]

def rand_word():

    fruit = ['grape','apple','pear','banana','orange', 'cherry']
    return fruit[random.randint(0,len(fruit))]

def main():
    print '\nWelcome to Hangman!\nYou are allowed 7 incorrect guesses before you lose the game. \nThe theme is fruit. Good luck!\n'
    game = Hangman(rand_word())
    while not game.hangman_loss():
            game.game_stats()
            player_choice = raw_input('\nEnter a letter: ')
            if len(player_choice)>= 2:
                    while True:
                            print '\nPlease only one letter at a time'
                            retry = raw_input('Try again: ')
                            if len(retry) == 1:
                                    game.guess(retry)
                                    break
                            else:
                                    continue
            else:
                    game.guess(player_choice)

    game.game_stats()       
    if game.hangman_win():
            print '\nGreat job! You have won Hangman!'
    else:
            print '\nSorry, but you did not win the game!'
            print 'The word was ' + game.word
            print 'Good try!'
            print

    answer = raw_input('Would you like to play again? (yes or no): ')
    print
    if answer == 'yes':
            main()
    else:
            print
            print ('Thanks for playing!')
            sys.exit()

main()
```

**Sometimes when I run it, it throws the error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Jackie
>   Carbert/Documents/GEOG 4880/hangmanTINKERing.py", line 135, in
>   
>       main()   File "C:/Users/Jackie Carbert/Documents/GEOG 4880/hangmanTINKERing.py", line 126, in main
>       main()   File "C:/Users/Jackie Carbert/Documents/GEOG 4880/hangmanTINKERing.py", line 126, in main
>       main()   File "C:/Users/Jackie Carbert/Documents/GEOG 4880/hangmanTINKERing.py", line 88, in main
>       game = Hangman(rand_word())   File "C:/Users/Jackie Carbert/Documents/GEOG 4880/hangmanTINKERing.py", line 82, in
>   rand_word
>       return fruit[random.randint(0,len(fruit))] IndexError: list index out of range

But only sometimes. Obviously I see that the error is referring to the function where I am picking one of the random fruits, but I do not see what, why or how the index is out of range?

Comment: Have you gone through all the docs for `random`?

Answer (score 0):

In the `return` statement of your `rand_word` function you need to minus 1 from `len(fruit)`, like this:

```
def rand_word():
    fruit = ['grape','apple','pear','banana','orange', 'cherry']
    return fruit[random.randint(0,len(fruit)-1)]
```

Python list indices start at 0 and therefore finish at "list length minus one".